# jQuery for loop and set active class

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to create loop with jQuery with 10 dynamic divs.
Here is my code:

```
data = '';
var cls = (total == i) ? "active" : null;
for ( var i = 1; i <=10; i++ ) {
    data += '<div class="list ' + cls + '">' + i + '</div>';
}
```

in the above I would like to apply active class to a number of selected items

total variable is dynamically created, so if  total is 5, first 5 divs should have class active applied to it.

Comment: Why is `i` being referenced outside the loop?

Comment: `data = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    data += '<div class="list ' + (total == i ? "active" : '') + '">' + i + '</div>';
}`

Comment: Move `var cls` in your loop. Then change `total == i` to `i <= total`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
data = '';
for ( var i = 1; i <=10; i++ ) {
    var cls = total <= i ? "active" : null;
    data += '<div class="list ' + cls + '">' + i + '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your condition inside the loop, so that for each iteration you can make the check for each iteration.

```
var data = '',
total = 5,
cls;
for ( var i = 1; i <=10; i++ ) {
    cls = (total >= i) ? "active" : '';
    data += '<div class="list ' + cls + '">' + i + '</div>';
}
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ey7M/)**

Comment: Don't you feel that a better way to insert/create `<div>`, since OP is already using jQuery, is to rely on the jQuery object, i.e. `$('<div />').addClass('list ' + cls)`?

Comment: I didn't see it was tagged with Jquery (because there was no use of it in the code snippet). I don't see it needed here though, as this is such a small manipulation of an element. If there were to be several classes added or a more advanced manipulation of the element then yes, It would make more sense to use jquery.

Comment: My bad. I must have confused it with something else ;) ignore my comment.